# Multiple class definitions in one tab (IntelliJ)

Tags: intellij-idea

Maybe I'm mistaken but I think in Eclipse it is possible to write something like

```
public class A{}
public class B{}

public class C{
   public static void main(string[] args){
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();
   }
}
```

in **the same tab**.

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ? Because if I do this in IntelliJ it tells me that "B should be declared in a file named 'B.java'".

Comment: You're mistaken. Java only allows you to have one public class defined in each .java file. This restriction does not depend on the IDE you're using.

Comment: I'm aware of this restriction. But this doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot define multiple classes in one "tab". The IDE would have taken care of that (i.e. compile each class to one .java-file.) I'm pretty sure I've seen people do it a dozen times in IDEs.

Comment: In any case, IntelliJ IDEA does not have this feature, and I'm fairly sure that neither do Eclipse or NetBeans.